# Multiple search / filter

Tags: php, forms, search, filter

I have this PHP form, everything it's ok but I want to search like in screenshot.

Search after **X** SKU if EAN is like **Y** or search after Interne Nr. **X** if EAN like **Y**

```
 select * 
    from **centralhub_logistik**
    where **sku** LIKE '%$search%'
    OR 
    **EAN** LIKE '%$search%'
    OR **InterneNr** LIKE '%$search%
    'LIMIT 0 , 50
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: Name all search field with unique names (f.e. search_sku, search_ean.) and then use them in MYSQL

Comment: Explain what you mean with X and Y? _“but I want to search like in screenshot”_ - that explains almost nothing … Use your _words_ to properly describe what exactly you want, do not just point at an image.

Comment: _“[foo] if EAN is like Y or [bar] if EAN like Y”_ - that’s the same “condition” both times, so there isn’t an actual “or” here.

Comment: In that "Photo", why does the second line in "Artikel" exist? Neither SKU nor EAN fit

Comment: IF SKU is LIKE " 8989898989 " and EAN LIKE " 20 " then show result

IF SKU is LIKE " 8989898989 " and EAN LIKE " 50 " show nothing